# can /usr/src be a sym link?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, source-code

I want to store all source code of programs I have installed in /usr/src. However, due to size of the drive I made a sym link /usr/src that points to ~/src. That was nice. Unfortunately, that caused virtualbox-dkms to fail to build the virtualbox kernel module because of a symlink within the linux-headers-*-common. 'script' points to ./../lib/linux-kbuild-3.1/scripts what is fine in /usr/src directory but wrong in ~/src.

Can I bypass this problem or the only solution is to store sources within the directory /usr/src?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making `/usr/src/` a [binding mount](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/mount_bind.html) fin having the following line in my */etc/fstab*

```
 /home/Src        /usr/src         none     bind             0 0
```

The directory `/home/Src` has to exist before the mount.

Binding mounts are a bit like symbolic links for mounts; so inside `/usr/src/Kernel` the `pwd` command gives `/usr/src/Kernel` (and not `/home/Src/Kernel` as would a symbolic link have given)